# My code keeps coming up with an error "AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'on_honor_roll'" what should I do to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, attributes, attributeerror

```
from Student import Student

student1 = Student("Oscar", "Accounting", 3.1)
student2 = Student("Phyllis", "Business", 3.8)

print(student1.on_honor_roll())

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name,  major, gpa):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa

        def on_honor_roll(self):
            if self.gpa >= 3.5:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

this is my code,and down below is the link to which video I was following.Please try to help me as it is so frustrating as I was stuck on this for weeks :( !!!!!

Comment: Could you post your code better formatted? Looked at it via edit, but that didn't help much. It does appear the `on_honor_roll` is intended one level too deeply. But not 100% sure.

Comment: you have an extra indent for `on_honor_roll`, pls intent it to left so that it's out of `__init__`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Student: 
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa): 
        self.name = name 
        self.major = major 
        self.gpa = gpa

    def on_honor_roll(self): # Correct the Indent Here
        if self.gpa >= 3.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

student1 = Student("Oscar", "Accounting", 3.1) 
student2 = Student("Phyllis", "Business", 3.8)

print(student1.on_honor_roll(), student2.on_honor_roll())
```

Output:

```
False True
```

The error you did:
`def on_honor_roll(self):` should be straight to `def __init__(self, name,  major, gpa):`I mean they should have same indent level.

Comment: 'straight to' is a bit vague. Best to clarify they should have the same level of indentation.

Comment: This answer seems to point out a problem that "was caused by a typo". Such questions are not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please flag or vote them as off-topic.